# Não consigo escrever um arquivo com usb otg

Tags: xamarin-forms

Eu consigo ler os arquivos na pasta do pen drive, mas não consigo escrever.

Este é o código que uso pra tentar escrever:

```
 string path = "./storage/A691-92EC";

                        string file1 = "usb.txt";


                        if (Directory.Exists(path))
                        {
                            var filename1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, file1);
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename1, "teste");

                        }
```

esse é o erro que dá:

> Access to the path "/storage/A691-92EC/usb.txt" is denied.

e essas são as permissões do android:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
```